# Newest Skype update from Microsoft changed my home page in firefox and ERASED my entire session

Tags: firefox, skype

Normally when I open my firefox I got pages that i had opened before closing my browser. Now I have useless http://metromsn.gazeta.pl and all sites are gone...

How can anyone think that it will be good decision?!

How can I restore all my pages that I have opened last time in Firefox before those morons silently changed my home page to and change option from loading last seession to load just home page?

**UPDATE**

If anyone is interested, exact url is: http://metromsn.pl?pc=UP22&ocid=univskyhp I wonder if anyone will be fired for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the History menu.  There's two options that I think could have those lost tabs/windows in them: `History->Recently Closed Tabs` and `History->Recently Closed Windows`.  There's also the `History->Restore Previous Session` option, but I doubt that will be available.  Otherwise, there's always the last resort option of opening the history and cherry picking what you want to reopen.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately "Restore previous session" wasn't available...